# What is the power spectral density of a DC signal?

Tags: digital-logic, ac, dc, communication, signal-processing

I am trying to find the Esd and psd of a pure DC signal, but I am stuck at integration of a square of Dirac delta function.

Comment: Pure DC has no AC component so your question is meaningless.

Comment: Yes, the only possible answer is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a (pure) DC signal, you have, at a frequency f :

$$ f \ne 0 => P(f) = 0 $$

And since your signal is pure DC, it is not a finite energy signal. So it's Energy Spectral Density is not defined.